# Degrading iText from 5.4.2 to 1.3

Tags: itext

I am trying to degrade iText from 5.4.2 to 1.3 as per project standards.

I am not able to find the class `BaseColor` in iText 1.3 and the methods `PDFTable.setKeepTogether(boolean)` and `PDFTable.flushContent()` are not available as part of 1.3 version.

What were the alternatives for these?

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why would you want to degrade to a 8-year-old version, that has potentially [technical and legal issues](http://lowagie.com/iText2)? Is that because of the Java version?

Comment: It's not a real question. See also the comment by Alexis Pigeon.

Comment: And do you honestly expect 1.3 to have the same functionality of 5.4.2? What do you think the iText developers have been doing these past 10 years?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iText 1.3, For color you need to use `java.awt.Color` class like
`new Color(255, 51, 51)`

Comment: Thanks. We do really need to degrade it as per recommondations. Please let me know the alternatives for the methods PDFTable.setKeepTogether(boolean) and PDFTable.flushContent() in itext 1.3. Thanks in advance

Comment: check tableFitsPage and cellsFitPage are availble!i'm not sure

Comment: btw if you are degrading iText for licence reason then you could use iTest 2.1.7. check the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321207/what-is-latest-version-of-itext-that-is-not-agpl?rq=1

Comment: if the answer is right to the question plz accept the answer by cliking tick mark near the voting arrows in question